# Recommend java framework to load a WSDL url/file, get a list of methods and etc

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws, wsdl4j

I have to implement a java component that will work with WSDL, do you aware of any frameworks that will simplify that solution and avoid me to reinvent the wheel (wsdl4j maybe ?)

Here is the basic operations i tend to support (the end user have to do all of these from UI, so there is no way to know in advance the wsdl url in order to generate classes, everything at runtime):

1. To be able to load a WSDL url so that the server will read its content, provide a list of available methods and know how to activate a web service call.
2. There shall be a possibility to load a local WSDL file.
3. In case WSDL url is provided, server shall support http and https formats
4. To be able to know the required parameters from the WSDL so that I will be able to configure the parameters and activate a web service call let's say on a scheduled base or any other trigger.
5. After loading the WSDL file I will get a list of required variables and their type
6. To be able to create an integration point so that I will be able to use this integration point along my applications (persist all these settings and mappings and execute webservice call whenever i need it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Apache CXF, plenty to read on it starting [here](http://cxf.apache.org/resources-and-articles.html), also a book, [Apache CXF web service development.](http://www.packtpub.com/apache-cxf-web-service-development/book)

Comment: Ok. thanks. Do you know if CXF can parse wsdl at runtime, so then I can retrieve the operations + params ? tried to find something about this, but read only about DynamicClient capabilities... is it what you're talking about ?